# Xamarin.iOS Crashlytics Crash Report on every try/catch

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin.ios, crashlytics

we are having a strange issue with Crashlytics reports, the console show us as a fatal exception also if the issue is handled in a try/catch block when the exception is thrown in native code.

[Here](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/issues/276) you can find a link where is all explained.

Someone knows how to fix this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi , if the same with that issue , you also can re-submit it there in Github .Then people will follow it up .

Comment: Hi @JuniorJiang-MSFT, thanks for the answer, could you please explain me how to do it ? Thanks

Comment: Okey , I have shared the link : https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/issues/new . Just editting problems in there and submit .

Comment: the issue has been resubmitted in GitHub https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/issues/352